# Continue Reading using XmlReader when exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `XmlReader` to parse a huge XML file.

My XML document is like this:

```
<Root>
     <Toys>
          <Toy>
             <Price></Price>
             <ToyName></ToyName>
          </Toy>
      </Toys>
</Root>
```

My `XmlReader` is reading each descendant which (`Toys`) using this code:

```
XmlReader.ReadToDescendant("Toys");
While(XmlReader.Read())
```

For each `Toys`element I load one single `Toy` in each loop
like this:

```
While(XmlReader.Read())
{
   XElement.Parse(BatchXmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
}
```

Now, how can I continue looping (With my `XmlReader`) to the next `Toy` if I have an parse Exception ("Xml is not well formed") in the line:

```
XElement.Parse(BatchXmlReader.ReadOuterXml());
```

I tried to try catch it and in the catch just use continue syntax.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post valid code, ideally in the form of a [mcve] - currently you've got `While` instead of `while`, so this clearly isn't your real code. Now, why are you trying to read ill-formed XML to start with? Have you looked at the XML to see what's wrong with it? Can you sort out whatever's *producing* the invalid XML? That would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Hello Jon, The Xml is not created by me- so my only way to validate it is to  parse each toy and toy. A toy that is invalid format (lets say unclosed tags) is logged as failed - but i still want to loop all the toys,What happens is that i fall in a catch statement  and the XmlReader finishes to loop.

Comment: Even though it's not created by you, you should go back to whoever *did* create it and complain. Get them to fix it if at all possible. There is no excuse for invalid XML...

Comment: Jon - Is there any solution how can i continue to read the next node (Toy) and not finish my looping all toys,

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if there wasn't. XML APIs are designed to read *valid* XML, and find errors in invalid XML. Again, getting valid XML would be *by far* the best solution here.

Comment: i am working on a 2-3 giga file= if one or two Toys are not a valid xml - i wish to continue to the next Toy. that is why i log the failed toys so i can retrieve the correct toy agian,   In a huge xml file i can"t stop reading the file because one or more toys are not valide Xml.

Comment: Could you show us the invalid xml parts?

Comment: I want to be prepared for all casses so an invalid xml part can be a unclosed tag for example.i am loading an xml to DOM so a validation there is.in catch i get the  message,

Comment: "i can"t stop reading the file because one or more toys are not valide Xml" - why not? Why can't you insist on being given valid XML? If you can't trust that it's *structurally* valid, why would you trust that the data in it is even slightly reasonable? It's really easy to produce valid XML, so I'm deeply mistrustful of anyone providing invalid XML. Again, I strongly urge you to go back to whoever created the XML file. (Aside from anything else, they're pushing the problem onto *everyone* reading the file. If they fix it, everyone wins. If you fix it somehow, only you benefit.)